# Translating during config phase (using angular-translate)

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm developing the i18n part of my Angular web app, and I'd like to use angular-translate in my config phase.

I defined some data that I'd like to translate:

```
.state('app.tracking', {
    url: '/:IdentityIdentifier',
    params:{
        IdentityIdentifier: {squash: false, value: null}
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/pages/tracking.html',
    data : { title: $filter('translate')('tracking.tracking.TITLE') },
    resolve: load([], function(){ return loadGoogleMaps(); })
})
```

Here's my config declaration:

```
.config(
  [          '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', 'MODULE_CONFIG', '$httpProvider', '$filter',
    function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider,   $locationProvider,   MODULE_CONFIG,   $httpProvider,   $filter) {
```

The error I get is classic: **Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $filter**

I'm aware I can't use services in config phase, only providers, but is there a solution to my problem?

**EDIT:** My problem has been solved by assigning the key *'tracking.tracking.TITLE'* to my *data.title* variable, then translating it using *translate* directive in my markup.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Really helpful. I even created a custom translation filter that I use in the `title` markup that suffixes the page title with a string that is dependant on the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like mentioned in the EDIT to the question: applying the filter in the markup is obviously the easiest solution.

Besides that, if one would really want to access services in config phase, then read on:

It is technically not possible in Angular <= 1.4.

Starting from Angular v1.5 (current rc version is 1.5.0-rc.0) it seems to be possible, **although I cannot recommend to do so**, because the config phase should just be the place where the services are configured before they're used for the first time.

[This is the change that made the following possible (link to angular.js repo at github)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/29a05984fe46c2c18ca51404f07c866dd92d1eec) (it was only made to allow decorating `$injector`).

Now, here comes the example:
http://codepen.io/NicBright/pen/PZJBPP?editors=101

JS part:

```
(function() {
  var result;

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(function($injectorProvider) {
    result = $injectorProvider.$get().get('myService').getSomething();
  })
  .factory('myService', function() {
    return { getSomething: function() { return 'it works!'; }}
  })
  .controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.result = result;
  })

})();
```

HTML part:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  result: {{ result }}
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Time to upgrade :)

Comment: Yeah. v1.5 will also bring multi transclusion to directives :-)
But please mind my edit that I do not think one should access services already in the config phase. I think that this "feature" was not added on purpose, so there could be side-effects.