# angular-translate not working with ui-grid and angular 1.5.5

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-translate

I am using:
angular-translate@2.6.0
ui-grid@3.0.1
angular@1.5.5

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
 $translate.use(langKey);
};
```

$translate.use(langKey); function will not translate my ui-grid cells. However when I will switch to angular@1.2.28 translate function is working. I cannot downgrade angular to 1.2.28 because other things will stop working.

here is plunkr example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UUFr1sN3uXjnnPGfFkdO?p=preview

can anyone help?
thanks

Comment: I hope this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832353/translating-during-config-phase-using-angular-translate